# Freemarker ISO string to datetime with timezone

Tags: string, datetime, freemarker, iso

I need to display the below "String" in the desired format

String str = `1979-01-24T00:00:00.000-08:00` 
Desired format: `Jan 24, 1979 00:00:00 AM PST`

Note: The tz in the str could be any tz not limited to PST. 
Tried the below but none worked:

- `str?datetime.iso` - Output is `Jan 24, 1979 2:00:00 AM CST` - This displays the date time in the format I need but the time is being converted from PST to CST.
- `str?string("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz")` - Error: Expected a method, but this has evaluated to a string
- `str?datetime?string("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz")` - Error: Unparseable date: "1979-01-24T00:00:00.000-08:00"
- `<#setting datetime_format="iso"> str?datetime` - `1979-01-24T02:00:00-06:00` - The timezone is changed.

Answer (score 1):

The timezone can be configured by the following setting, as refer to their documentation https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html

```
<#setting time_zone ="PST">
<#assign str = "1979-01-24T00:00:00.000-08:00">
${str?datetime.iso}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that FreeMarker parses date/time values to `java.util.Date` (and its subclasses), which don't store a time zone anymore, as it always stores the value in UTC. So that information is lost after parsing. As of 2.3.30, the only solution I see to do this in Java (with Java 8 `ZonedDateTime`).

Comment: Is there anyway I can supply the tz offset (-08:00) to the functions to preserve the tz. I prefer to do the conversion in the ftl than in Java. Something like 'datetime.iso(tzoffset)'. offset = 08:00

Comment: @harsh_t No, there's no such option. Probably there won't be either, because this problem will be solved when FreeMarker will "natively" support `ZonedDateTime`, etc. If it really has to be done purely in FTL, maybe you can do an ugly hack: remove the time zone before parsing, then put it back after formatting.